# Using T type parameter to clone a collection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I want to clone a collection with the following method and I want to know if it can be optimized:

```
public T CloneCollection<T>(IEmployees employees) where T : IEmployees, new()
{
    T collection = new T();
    foreach (IEmployee employee in employees)
    {
        collection.Add(employee);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

These are the other classes which are related to the method above:

```
public class RegularEmployee : Entities, IEmployee
{
//properties
}

public class User : Entities, IEmployee
{
//properties
}

public class Manager : Entities, IEmployee
{
//properties
}

public class ManagerCollection : List<Manager>, IEmployees
{
   void Add(IEmployee employee);
}

public class RegularEmployeeCollection : List<RegularEmployee>, IEmployees
{
   void Add(IEmployee employee);
}

public class UserCollection : List<User>, IEmployees
{
   void Add(IEmployee employee);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for IEmployee, IEmployees and also the code behind Add methods from your xxxCollection types? CodeReview requires that all relevant code is provided.

Comment: How about a `HumanBeing`, or some such  base class - perhaps an `abstract` class -  and implement `Clone` there.  And perhaps the way to clone in this case is to `serialize` the object and then `un-serialize` it; which of course effectively makes a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your loop with `AddRange()`:

```
public T CloneCollection<T>(IEmployees employees) where T : IEmployees, new()
{
    T collection = new T();
    collection.AddRange(employees);
}
```

Additional thought:

Note that your solution and this solution are simply cloning the list and not the items in the list.  If you update an `Employee`, the employee will be modified in both lists.  If this is NOT the desired behavior, you will need to clone each employee as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### Review

Your code does not clone a collection. It creates one and assigns the values of the specified source collection to it. It also lacks proper generics to make this usable for other types of collections.

> ```
> public T CloneCollection<T>(IEmployees employees) where T : IEmployees, new()
> {
>     // creates a target collection
>     T collection = new T();
>
>     // assigns items from source to target
>     foreach (IEmployee employee in employees)
>     {
>         collection.Add(employee);
>     }
>     return collection;
> }
> ```

Cloning a collection is **ambiguously** defined. It does not state whether the items should be cloned as well.

#### Shallow Clone

A shallow clone of a collection is a new instance, holding references to the same items as the source collection.

```
public static T ShallowClone<T, TItem>(T source) where T : ICollection<TItem>, new()
{
    var target = new T();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        target.Add(item);
    }
    return target;
}
```

I don't really see a use case for this. It's better using common collections or creating overloaded constructors on custom collections that take `IEnumerable<T>` as input. If your custom collection inherits from `List<T>` you should take advantage of `AddRange`.

#### Deep Clone

A deep clone of a collection is a new instance with clones of the source items. Make sure the items implement `ICloneable`. If you want to provide deep-cloning for items that do not implement this interface, you'd have to create an overload of `DeepClone` that uses a default strategy for deep-cloning items. This is elaborated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically).

```
public static T DeepClone<T, TItem>(T source) 
    where T : ICollection<TItem>, new()
    where TItem : ICloneable
{
    var target = new T();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        target.Add(item == null ? null : item.Clone());
    }
    return target;
}
```

*Checking input for null is left out for brevity.*